# SendInput() of an input array to STEAM CLIENT

Tags: c++, winapi, sendinput

I'm trying to simulate a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> keypress (and release) by using the `INPUT` struct in windows.h, but I can only get it to work in simple programs such as notepad, whereas in the Steam client it doesn't actually write to it:

```
    INPUT ip[4];
    ip[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip[0].ki.wScan = 0;
    ip[0].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    ip[0].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    ip[0].ki.time = 0;
    ip[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    ip[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip[1].ki.wScan = 0;
    ip[1].ki.dwFlags = 0;
    ip[1].ki.wVk = 0x56;
    ip[1].ki.time = 0;
    ip[1].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    ip[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip[2].ki.wScan = 0;
    ip[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    ip[2].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    ip[2].ki.time = 0;
    ip[2].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    ip[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip[3].ki.wScan = 0;
    ip[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    ip[3].ki.wVk = 0x56;
    ip[3].ki.time = 0;
    ip[3].ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    SendInput((sizeof(ip)/sizeof(INPUT)), ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

What am I doing / thinking wrong?
Full code: https://pastebin.com/CxCfeJar

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: Actually it does work, you are right. I realize now that the problem is that it doesn't write to the particular window that I want it to write to. (It writes to Notepad but not to Steam for example). Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: Call `SetForegroundWindow(targetWindow_hwnd)` so keyboard messages go to that window.

Comment: Please check my update of the post(pastebin - full code), I do have SetForegroundWindow in my code?  
in main()

Comment: Is this a Win32 program or something odd? Give some information about "Steam" You can use Visual Studio's Spy.exe to get windows class information from "Steam"

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/f72b22a4d48da96f13e6b0711a813ef5.mp4
I dont know what information is of relevance, so I made a gif of it all in spy++.

Also I noticed that If i do     SendInput(2, ip, sizeof(INPUT));
It pastes correctly in Steam. However it won't release the key CTRL and V from pushdown afterwards (obviously) - which is a problem. So It feels like I am indeed targeting the correct window.

Comment: UI Automation is done using [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Comment: I dont quite get what you mean, I am just simulating a Ctrl+v click? It shouldnt really have anything to do with UI Automation? Isn't it just as if i Ctrl+v:ed myself? I dont understand why my code doesn't work for "Steam" but for textdocument.

Comment: Thus question is asked here every single day. Try a bit of research.